# Url stop loading inbetween on UIWebView and WKWebView. On iOS 11 only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview, ios11

My URL

- https://app.educationgalaxy.com/games/ipadgame.html?retries=3&name=blastoff&rocket=3&level=2&score=0&gameTimer=150

My Findings

- The URL works perfectly with all safari and other browsers.
  (including iOS 11 mobile safari)
- The URL works with all iOS versions other than iOS 11.
- I tried to open the URL on both UIWebView and WKWebView but the same issue happens on both. i.e URL stops loading near completion and
  nothing happens then.

Here is what I tried so far

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    // Objects
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupWebView()
        loadUrl()
    }

    func setupWebView() {

        let prefs = WKPreferences()
        prefs.javaScriptEnabled = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences = prefs

        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    func loadUrl() {

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "https://app.educationgalaxy.com/games/ipadgame.html?retries=3&name=blastoff&rocket=3&level=2&score=0&gameTimer=150")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadRevalidatingCacheData
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print(webView.url!)

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        print(webView.url!)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

        print("error  - \(error)")
    }

}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: from iOS 11, It won't work if any UI things (even if you access UIApplication) executed in non-main thread. Following is the error I got.    "CoreAnimation: [EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread in an implicit transaction! Note that this may be unsafe without an explicit CATransaction or a call to [CATransaction flush]."

Comment: Thank you for the comments. As you can see I am trying to load the URL from the main thread. What I tried is like created an application and created a WKwbview in viewDidLoad and requested to load the URL. The URL is started loading but it stops somewhere middle of loading. And this happens only on ios 11, every other version loads the URL perfectly.

Comment: Did you find any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have analyse your code that is good and you  have need check image formate.When I am using bellow code with  image url link working fine .

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  ,WKNavigationDelegate {


    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupWebView()
        loadUrl()
    }

    func setupWebView() {

        let prefs = WKPreferences()
        prefs.javaScriptEnabled = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences = prefs

        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    func loadUrl() {

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
       // let url = URL(string: "https://app.educationgalaxy.com/games/ipadgame.html?retries=3&name=blastoff&rocket=3&level=2&score=0&gameTimer=150")!

         let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Snake_River_%285mb%29.jpg")!


        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadRevalidatingCacheData
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print(webView.url!)

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        print(webView.url!)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

        print("error  - \(error)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand, can you please explain what I have to do in my case.

Comment: The issue is not for every URLs, my particular URL is not working on webview.

Comment: First you have to login web view (hard code ) and keep the session and when got the success need to call same Url what ever you calling

Comment: The URL here I am using is a public URL which doesn't require any authentication.

Comment: We got same  issue with my colleagues

Comment: If you find a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

WkWebview is recently introduced and UIWebView is officially deprecated now.
Here is link on same issue posted on Apple forum.And Apple staff is currently figuring out the crash.
[enter link description here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90411)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90411
Also try to add WKWebView.framework in your project.
And Transport Security.
Hope this information can help you.

Comment: Thank you. As you said I can see other peoples are also reporting WebKit related issues. In our case, the URL is loading and we can track the progress. Unfortunately, loading stops before completion(we have no crashes). I have added webkit.framework but still no changes. Our url is HTTPS so ATS doesn't have any role on this even though I permitted all web access but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

// Add plist file

```
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>google.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

```
 if WKWebView don't not support then declare .m file below code:



#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface WebScannerViewController()
{

 WKWebView *webView;

}
```

@end

@implementation WebScannerViewController
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

```
[super viewDidLoad];
webView.hidden=YES;

webView.UIDelegate = self;
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
self.loadingSign.hidden = NO;


    webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 94, Width, Height-128);
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
     webView.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17";
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.educationgalaxy.com/games/ipadgame.html?retries=3&name=blastoff&rocket=3&level=2&score=0&gameTimer=150"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

}